# How to load a font file in vuejs and webpack?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, less

I did a lot of reading but none of the links show me exactly how to add fonts in vuejs.
This is how I import the font in my less file.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Questrial";
  src: url("../../fonts/Questrial-Regular.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Galano_Grotesque_extra_Bold";
  src: url("../../fonts/Galano_Grotesque_Bold.otf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Galano_Grotesque_Bold";
  src: url("../../fonts/Galano_Grotesque_DEMO_Bold.otf");
}
```

This is the error that i get

> ERROR in
>   ./src/themes/jatango-theme/components/fonts/Galano_Grotesque_Bold.otf
>   1:4 Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:4) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type. (Source code omitted for
>   this binary file)

I am a newbie to VUEJS with no previous knowledge of react or angular.
I only know jquery and javascript. So please someone give me a step by step guide to include the fonts. Thanks in advance :)

[image: folder-structure]

[image: Folder-structure]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope this will help others who are facing the same issue. For some reason Vue.js is giving error when using `.otf` files. I used `.woff` and now everything works fine. Use the following code in your `webpack.config.js` file :

```
      module.exports = function (config, { isClient, isDev }) {
            module: { rules: [ { test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?.*$|$)/, 
            loader: 'file-loader' } ] }
            return config }
```

and import the files in your css file using something like this

```
 @font-face { 
       font-family: "Questrial";
       src: url("../../fonts/Questrial-Regular.ttf"); 
   }
```

Answer (score 7):

Put your fonts in the `public/fonts/` folder.
In css or scss, specify the path starting with `/fonts/`.

**Example scss:**

```
$font-dir: "/fonts/";

@font-face {
  font-family: "NameFont";
  src: url("#{$font-dir}NameFontRegular/NameFontRegular.eot");
  src: url("#{$font-dir}NameFontRegular/NameFontRegular.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"),
  url("#{$font-dir}NameFontRegular/NameFontRegular.woff") format("woff"),
  url("#{$font-dir}NameFontRegular/NameFontRegular.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Next, import your scss into main.js

**Example:**

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
import styles from './assets/scss/main.scss';
```

---

or in `vue.config.js`

**Example:**

```
module.exports = {
...
  css: {
    modules: true,
    loaderOptions: {
      css: {
        localIdentName: '[name]-[hash]',
        camelCase: 'only'
      },
      sass: {
        data: '@import "~@/assets/scss/import/_variables.scss"; @import "~@/assets/scss/import/_mixins.scss";'
      },
    },
  },
...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a webpack error. You are missing a [webpack loader](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/) to manage font files. Usually I use [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) for fonts:

```
{
  test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
  use: {
    loader: "file-loader",
    options: {
      name: "fonts/[name].[ext]",
    },
  },
}
```

Add this code in your [webpack config file](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#configuration) (module > rules section) or if you're using vue-cli 3, in your [vue.config.js](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack) file (configurewebpack section).

Comment: i get this error when i try to do this -> "yarn add file-loader --save-dev"

error Running this command will add the dependency to the workspace root rather than the workspace itself, which might not be what you want - if you really meant it, make it explicit by running this command again with the -W flag (or --ignore-workspace-root-check).

Comment: With `yarn`, it's `--dev` not `--save-dev` 

Comment: also this is my webpack.config.js file contents --> module.exports = function (config, { isClient, isDev }) {
  return config
} can you give me the exact code to be used there to load my fonts. That will be really helpful

Comment: in the options what if i need to add multiple fonts? how do I do that? As of now one font is added and the rest are giving me same error.

Comment: Your `webpack.config.js` is really short... you must have another config file with a real webpack configuration

Comment: I finally got it working with some changes to your code. For some reason VUEJS gives error when using .otf files. Rest everything works fine. thanks again :)